# How to change the title of histograms created with pairs.panel()?

Tags: r, histogram, psych

I used this function of the `psych` library to see the correlations of 3 samples with each other. While I could change the main title, I could not change the names of the histograms on the diagonal of the 3x3 graph. These take the names of the samples by default. How can I change the names of the histograms I'm talking about?

I did some research about it on the internet or tried to ask chatgpt but I couldn't find any information. I couldn't find anything in the documentation either.
Here is my code:

```
pairs.panels(PartC[, c("Energy_consumption", "Energy_production", "CO2_emission")], 
             main = "The Correlation Between Energy Production, Energy Consumption, and the Amount of CO2 Emission.")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the `colnames` of your data to the names you want to show in the plot. I use the built-in dataset `iris` as an example like this:

```r
library(psych)  
data(iris)
d = iris[1:4]
colnames(d) = c("A", "B", "C", "D")
pairs.panels(d, bg=c("red","yellow","blue"),
             main="Title")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-05-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: So how can I change the font size of these titles?